# Div overlay height issue

Tags: html, css, scroll, overlay

Hy guys.

I have a situation of overlay div inside another div.

Why the main div not fit the height size when i using position relative in a inner div to create a overlay.

[See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCzm3.jpg)
I cannot use position: absolute because i need the scroll working inside the main div.

See the code:

```css
    div.main
    {
       width: 300px; height: auto;
     border: solid 1px black; overflow: auto;
    }
 div.box1
    {

        width: 350px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px red;
    }
 div.box2
    {

     position: relative; top: -52px; left: 0px; z-index: 1;
     width: 350px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px green;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
 <div class="box1">box 1</div>
 <div class="box2">box 2 - overlay</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can use another css settings but i need to sinc the scroll of the inner divs.

Comment: Because it's positioned relative to it's normal/natural position, in someway it acts like it's still there though it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you need:

```css
 div.main
    {
       width: 300px; height: auto;
     border: solid 1px black; overflow: auto;
      
    position: relative;
    }
 div.box1
    {

        width: 350px; height: 50px; border: solid 1px red;
    }
 div.box2
    {

     position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 350px;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
 <div class="box1">box 1</div>
 <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative` still keeps the original space free for its element - it only moves the element away from its original position by the top/bottom/left/right values. But the free space is still where it is without those settings. A wrapping container with aut height will act as if the relatively positioned element still were at its original position, causing what you brought up in your question.

So to force a solution as you seem to want it, you'll have to use a fixed height and `overflow-y: hidden` on your container element.

```css
div.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 52px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

div.box1 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

div.box2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -52px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 350px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box1">box 1</div>
    <div class="box2">box 2 - overlay</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: which I explained, yes. There's no real solution to this problem, just an answer why it doesn't work as the OP expected, and a workaround to force it to act as expected.